# Dark Colours are just Black - Contrast is more compared to Windows

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, xorg, display, color-management

I recently switched to Arch from Windows, and I noticed that dark colours seem darker. Often it's just pitch black. Since the same image looks different on Windows and Linux, the colours' RGB values must be the same. They just render differently.

Here's an example image. The one on the left is the original and to the right is the same image I edited (because the image itself does not change) to show approximately what the problem looks like:
[image: Estimate of what it looks on Windows (left) vs on Linux (right)]
Dark colours are just black.

Changing monitor settings helps very little. That's not the issue.
I changed gamma values using `xgamma -gamma f.f`, and made the dark colours visible, but everything got washed out.

I looked for [colour profiles online](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ICC_profiles), but I need to get calibration software and hardware. I just want to make dark colours a little brighter so I can see.
I got [`DisplayCal`](https://displaycal.net/) and tried making a profile using *Synthetic ICC*. It was too complicated, and I don't know what all the parameters mean.

What am I missing? Is there a way to adjust contrast or the gamma curve? Is it NVIDIA? Is making a custom ICC profile viable?

<sub>*I'm running Gnome with Xorg.

i7 7800x, GTX 1050Ti*</sub>

Comment: Which drivers are you using (nouvaeu or nvidia)?  Also, do you know which engine (DirectX, OpenGL, Vulkan) the game uses?   Is that different on Windows?

Comment: @Stewart I'm using NVIDIA drivers.
I don't think the engine affects the appearance since the effect exists regardless of the program I'm using.